# CTL trouble translating text into formula

Tags: logic, computation-tree-logic, modal-logic

I have an excercise where I have to translate verbally formulated statements into CTL formulas. I have particularly trouble with this one:

> On every path q is true at least once and p was true sometime before, after
> no longer.
> My attempt is the following: $AF q \land (EF p) AU q$

This is obvously wrong. The first part is easy, then the second is more difficult. What I've stated there implies that there exists a path to $p$ before $q$ but not that $p$ was true on the previous path, and the third part to me looks impossible. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{AF}{\text{AF}\;}\newcommand{AG}{\text{AG}\;}$Try to decode this:

For each path:

- In the future: p and

  - In the future q and

    - Always in the future not p

---

You correctly concluded that the correct formula is

$$ \AF \left( p \land \AF \left( q \land \AG \neg p \right) \right).$$

The key thing to understand about CTL is that when you evaluate things like $\AF (p \land \AF q)$ then this is true if somewhere in the future $p \land \AF q$ is true, which means that $\AF q$ is evaluated in the state where $p$ is true.

Comment: $AF(p \land AF(q \land AF AG(-p)))$

Comment: The problem is I dont know how to express "in the future" because I only have aviable $A$ and $E$

Comment: I always feel bad if dont get the hints people give me sorry xD. Im going to try it again. I already knew what that meant, there are even more great combinations :)

Comment: Im just thinking about how to state for all path excluded the path i've already been

Comment: I think I see. Due to the stacked and we find automatically the structure of a series.

Comment: Thank you for help